# Cocos2d CCTouchBegan

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch

I'm trying to create a program where when the user touches the screen, a sprite will appear. However, if the user keeps their finger on that Sprite, the sprite will grow bigger until the user lets it go.

Now, I created this program in Cocos2d 1.x and it worked fine. However, when I attempted it in 2.x, the sprite gets created but it doesn't help the Sprite Grow. 
The code is the following:

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

redBall = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Circle.png"];
redBall.position = ccp(touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
redBallRect = CGRectMake(redBall.anchorPoint.x, redBall.anchorPoint.y, redBall.contentSize.width, redBall.contentSize.height);

[self addChild:redBall];




if (CGRectContainsPoint(redBallRect, touchLocation )) {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    growForever = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCScaleBy actionWithDuration: .5 scale: 1.2]];
    [growForever setTag:1];
    [redBall runAction:growForever];

}

return YES;

}
```

What might be the problem and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you enabled touch:

```
-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

      self.touchEnabled = YES;
}
```

Use boundingBox to get rect.

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
    touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];


    if(CGRectContainsPoint([redBall boundingBox], touchLocation))
    {
        NSLog(@"Hello");
        growForever = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCScaleBy actionWithDuration: .5 scale: 1.2]];
        [growForever setTag:1];
        [redBall runAction:growForever];

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess it's much easier to use BoundingBox.